# slope intercept german

Tags: terminology, slope

I have two interrelated  (and inter-cultural) questions.

1- How does one say slope-intercept (form) in German (although the question might also be placed in the German language StackExchange, I think math is the right venue as it is related to mathematics terminology)?

2- Is there a difference between the American convention of the representation of slope-intercept formula (y=mx+b) and the German way of writing that formula?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In German the equation $y=mx+b$ is called "Geradengleichung mit Steigung $m$". A reference here is [wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geradengleichung), see "Haupt-oder Normalform".

Edit: The Japanese version of Wikipedia gives
直線の傾き・切片標準形 (slope–intercept form),
$y=mx+b$, for interested readers.

Comment: nice translation!!

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer. Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 0):

The german way off calculating the y-intercept is a little different, though the basic idea is the same. Based on my research, the german y-intercept form is y=m(x−x1)+y1. I believe they also call this Die Gleichung der Geraden. I hope this was helpful.